# V8 NewInstance failing when ObjectTemplate has a Date member

Tags: c++, google-chrome, embedded-v8, libv8

Is V8 Broken or am I?

I want to add a JS Date to a Object available in the global object. This works with a older version (4.9.385.28) but fails with (5.0.71.33)... see output

g++ -I/usr/local core.c -o testCore -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x -lv8 -lv8_libplatform -lv8_libbase

core.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "include/libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "include/v8.h"
#include "time.h"

using namespace v8;

class ArrayBufferAllocator : public v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator
{
    public:
    virtual void* Allocate(size_t length) { void* data = AllocateUninitialized(length); return data == NULL ? data : memset(data, 0, length); }
    virtual void* AllocateUninitialized(size_t length) { return malloc(length); }
    virtual void Free(void* data, size_t) { free(data); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize V8.
    V8::InitializeICU();
    V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    Platform* platform = platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    V8::InitializePlatform(platform);
    V8::Initialize();

    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    ArrayBufferAllocator allocator;
    Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = &allocator;
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
    Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

    // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate,NULL,ObjectTemplate::New(isolate));
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    Local<ObjectTemplate> activity = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
    // @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    // ************************ This line breaks the NewInstance() call (5.0.71.33) works in (4.9.385.28) *****************************
    // @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    activity->Set        (String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "createddate", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(),     Date::New(isolate,time(NULL)*1000.0));

    Local<Object> activityInst = activity->NewInstance();
    context->Global()->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "activity", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(), activityInst);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../src/heap/heap.cc, line 3564
# Check failed: map->instance_type() == JS_REGEXP_TYPE || map->instance_type() == JS_OBJECT_TYPE || map->instance_type() == JS_ARRAY_TYPE.
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

1: V8_Fatal
2: v8::internal::Heap::CopyJSObject(v8::internal::JSObject*, v8::internal::AllocationSite*)
3: v8::internal::Factory::CopyJSObjectWithAllocationSite(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite>)
4: v8::internal::JSObjectWalkVisitor<v8::internal::DummyContextObject, (v8::internal::BoilerplateKind)1>::StructureWalk(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>)
5: v8::internal::JSObjectWalkVisitor<v8::internal::DummyContextObject, (v8::internal::BoilerplateKind)1>::StructureWalk(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>)
6: v8::internal::JSObject::DeepCopyApiBoilerplate(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>)
7: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InstantiateObject(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ObjectTemplateInfo>, bool)
8: v8::internal::ApiNatives::InstantiateObject(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ObjectTemplateInfo>)
9: v8::ObjectTemplate::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>)
10: main
11: start
12: 0x1
Illegal instruction
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add javascript objects to ObjectTemplates.   You can only add templates.   This changed between the versions you mention.

The idea, I think, is that a template will be instantiated many times and associating the same object with each of them doesn't make sense.  Whereas associated templates will also be re-instantiated giving different sub-objects for each parent object.

You're free to associate anything with the resulting object after NewInstance() is called, though.